# ConsoleLoggerProvider could not be found as a type or namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dbcontext

I'm using the loggingfactory while onconfiguring my database context file and in the example exercises they use a consoleloggingprovider but it in my exercise it says that i can't find the name or type and there is no reference in the example exercise to the consolelogginprovider and i've checked all the import and thats not problem.
Here is my code but it really isn't a code issue, i've got no clue what it could be.

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
 {

           var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(providers: new[]
        {
              new ConsoleLoggerProvider((category, level)
                    => category == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name
                       && level == LogLevel.Information, true)
        });

        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) //only configure the connection if the parameterless contructor was used (no options where provided).
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LotteryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            //TODO: tell EF (Entity Framework) that is going to operate against a SQL Server database using the connection string in the app.config of the UI project
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is available in a Nuget package search for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console in the package manager in Visual Studio or download it [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/2.2.0).